# Why are the "sequence of tenses" rules not observed in some special cases?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

An excerpt from an article on Yahoo: "The disappearances of two top Taliban figures from public view have prompted a spokesperson to deny that one of them had died, multiple outlets reported".

In the books on English Grammar the Present Perfect tense is described as involving a span of time from earliest memory to the present, i.e. the situation is expected to extend to the present moment (depicts some indefinite event(s)) or depicting past actions the effects of which continue up to the present time. Thus it makes Present Perfect appropriate to also introduce a topic of discourse or be used in the news (as it is in the pattern).

But in the pattern the action (of *prompting*) is implied to be finished before a definite moment in the past (before *outlets reported*). So abiding by the rules of "sequence of tenses" it should be put in the Past Perfect tense: *The disappearances of two top Taliban figures from public view had prompted...*

Is using Present Perfect here being an exception to the rule? If so, what are other exceptions when the "sequence of tenses" principles can or shall be not observed?

Comment: It might help in getting more clarity, if you could highlight what you think is the Present Perfect & Past Perfect & Simple Past in the given sentence. It might help even more, if you could explain where you think the Problem is. [[ Currently, I see that two moderators have voted to close this Post, but your clarifying edits might reverse that. ]] I have read the given sentence; It makes Perfect Sense.

Comment: @Prem moderators can be identified by the diamond badge. The 3 people who voted to close this question are users like yourself but maybe with a little more rep than you.

Comment: Eugene, you have not added any explanation in your question and this makes it seem you are a beginner. Where does a user begin to explain their answer if you don't show what you understand? The answer could take ages to write, it's a  very large topic.

Comment: Questions such as yours have been asked a considerable number of times. Hundreds of posts about the Present Perfect, Past Perfect, and the Simple Past. Did you try searching?  If you **edit your question**, showing your understanding of the Present Perfect and Simple Past, it would help users see why you were confused and they might vote to reopen the Q.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I'm not a beginner, of course. This question is not as simple at it may seem. The construction doesn't fall under the general rules of Pres.Perfect usage. Most part of the English Language study books are aimed at just cramming students without giving formidable knowledge. That is why it's hard for non-native speakers to understand the construction in question.

Comment: Like I said before, if you don't **explain** anything, no one will know. I am not a mind reader, you are a complete stranger to me, I don't know what you know. No one is going to start writing about the differences between Pres Perfect, the Past Perfect and the Simple Past unless they understand why you are confused.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22present+perfect%22+%22past+perfect%22+%22simple+past%22

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The underlying problem is posed by the Pres.Perfect ability to denote recurrent actions in a past time lapse. That is why the construction in the pattern can be often taken in by non-native learners in the following way: as if the spokesperson had been prompted not once or twice (for ten times in an hour, for example). And here only native speakers can say for sure what it really implies.

Comment: Please don't respond in the comments, **edit your question** if you feel it should be reopened. The number of reopen votes is just three.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see what the past participle has to do with it. Why would it be clearer without the past particle? (*The disappearances of two top FBI officers from public view have prompted a spokesperson for the mob to deny their involvement.*)

Comment: @Peter Shor Maybe it's difficult for native speakers to understand the ambiguousness that is put up by non-native learners. We can't say for sure whether there is a single action or a series of identical actions implied. Even by your example I can't twig  it definitely: for how many times was a spokesperson for the mob prompted to come out and deny the disappearance? (he could've been prompted by FBI and then by the police and then by the public and it might have taken place many times)

Comment: If it's ambiguous, why does it really matter? I don't see any practical difference it makes in the original sentence how many times the spokesperson was prompted. Do you use different tenses in your language for being prompted once and being prompted many different times?

Comment: @Peter Shor It can be of the greater importance when it comes to, for example, justice practice. "The police officer have prompted his subordinate to illegally ransack the aggrieved". It matters severely for the sentence term whether it was a single episode or the criminal act has taken place many times.

Comment: Then to make sure it was not ambiguous, we could say *"The police officer has **repeatedly** prompted his subordinate to illegally ransack the aggrieved."* or maybe *"On June 17, the police officer prompted his subordinate to illegally ransack the aggrieved".*

Comment: To summarize my last two comments, this sequence of tenses is actually ambiguous in English, but there are easy ways to remove the ambiguity when it matters. Any prosecutor who would use present perfect without clarifying that the police officer prompted his subordinate to do something illegal more than once is incompetent.

Comment: @Peter Shor Having mulled my question over more closely I finally twigged that it was the snag of sequence of tenses I had been striking all that time. But the moderators have banned me from asking questions for half a year.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here, because it is too long for a comment. I might change it if the OP clarifies.

Given Sentence:

> "The disappearances of two top Taliban figures from public view have prompted a spokesperson to deny that one of them had died, multiple outlets reported"

Breaking it up:
Two Taliban figures have disappeared and not seen in public (in last 5 days).
Hence, people started thinking (4 days ago) that this is because one of these Taliban figures has died.
In reality, he may be hiding or escaped to somewhere else or hospitalized or injured.
Taliban heard these rumors (3 days ago); these rumors **have** prompted a spokesperson to come out (2 days ago) to deny that he has died.
What the spokesperson said has being reported by "multiple outlets" maybe 2 days ago, but more likely, a little while before this Yahoo article was written.

The Crux of your Question:
Here, "These rumors **have** Prompted...." could also be written "These rumors **had** Prompted...."

This is because newspapers use tenses like that. It helps reduce the number of words in printing, and makes the news look fresh.
Consider "Biden has won" to "Biden wins".

More about Newspaper Tenses:
https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page12.shtml
https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/268001-Tenses-usage-in-news-reports
https://harshdivya.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/the-uses-of-the-present-tense-in-headlines-and-past-tense-in-news-reports/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present
https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/learning/general/weblines/521.html

Comment: Thank you for your heeding me question (I really don't understand why the moderators persistently would not like questions on grammar that may seem useful for many non-native linguistics studying students). In my perception the time referred to lies in the demesne of the past, i.e. "outlets reported (2 days ago, for example - Simple Past here) that one of the Taliban leaders had died (3-4-5...days ago - Past Perfect)" - it's OK for me. I can't twig what time sphere "have prompted" (Present Perfect) belongs to.

Comment: I could easily perceive Past Perfect here because a spokesperson had been prompted and began to deny. The fact of his [a spokesperson] having been prompted obviously took (or had been taking) place before the outlets reported.

Comment: OK, I will update the answer including your assumed timelines; Hope that helps you to make sense out of that sentence.

Comment: Thank you really. The origin of my question lies in the fundamental Grammars from which we know that, furthermore, Pres.Perfect denotes recurrent actions in a past time lapse. That is why I took in the construction "The disappearances of two top Taliban figures from public view have prompted a spokesperson to deny..." as if the spokesperson had been prompted not once or twice (for ten times in an hour, for example).

Comment: You should look more into the News Paper tenses and things should become clear. It seems you are wondering about two Core Issues: (1) "Prompted" should be taken to mean "Motivated", which may have happened just once and not necessarily repeatedly & (2) Present tense "have Prompted" should be Past tense "had Prompted", which is because of Historical Present or News Paper tenses.